# Symfony2 - print message on non-console event

Tags: php, symfony, command

I've started to refactor one of my Commands in Symfony2 (2.7) application. Quick question - **Is there any way to write an event listener that listens to an custom event and handles it by printing a message on a screen?**
Suppose there is some class that emits an event, for example, on successful save into the db. I need to listen for that event and when it's emitted, I want to print a message on a screen: "Your entity has been saved successfully" and I don't want to do it in command code because in my opinion when there are too many outputs in commands, the `execute` method becomes a bit messy. That's why I started to search for another way of handling system events with proper information for the user.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try  [ConsoleLogger](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/logger.html) ?

Comment: Looks good, but I cannot use it in DI. Suppose I want to print coloured text on some doctrine event. What then?

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible